# Parse REST api response for different possible classes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, .net-5, restsharp

I'm working with a REST API, that returns 2 different kinds of XML responses for the same request.

For example if I ask for a ticket using some ticket number, say `12345` to this API, it either returns:

1. The ticket:

[image]

2. Or says that it doesn't have the ticket:

[image]

(I couldn't format my XML for some reason so just pasted the screenshot.)

Note that the status code comes to be `Ok` in both the cases. I'm aware that it's a bad api design but we can't change anything about it.

With some help from this [JSON2Csharp](https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp) website, I came up with these classes to represent the response:

The Ticket class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tickets")]
public class TicketsResponse
{
    public List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } = new List<Ticket>();
    public bool HasTickets() => Tickets.Any();
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Ticket")]
public class Ticket
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Field1", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeField1() { return Field1 != null; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TicketNumber")]
    public int TicketNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SomeOtherDetails")]
    public SomeOtherDetails SomeOtherDetails { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Accessorials")]
    public object Accessorials { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SomeOtherDetails")]
public class SomeOtherDetails
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SomeOtherField1", IsNullable = true)]
    public string SomeOtherField1 { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeSomeOtherField1() { return SomeOtherField1 != null; }
}
```

The Error class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public byte requestId { get; set; }
    public byte errorCode { get; set; }
    public string errorDesc { get; set; }
    public ErrorResponseBody body { get; set; }
    public bool HasErrors()
    {
        var hasTopLevelError = errorCode != 0;
        var hasErrorBody = body?.errors?.Any() ?? false;

        if (hasTopLevelError || hasErrorBody)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public string ErrorMessage()
    {
        var hasTopLevelError = errorCode != 0;
        var hasErrorBody = body?.errors?.Any() ?? false;
        if (hasTopLevelError)
        {
            return errorDesc;
        }
        else if (hasErrorBody)
        {
            return string.Join(", ", body.errors.Select(e => e.errorDescription));
        }

        return null;
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "body")]
public class ErrorResponseBody
{
    [XmlElement("errors")]
    public List<Error> errors { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Error")]
public class Error
{
    public byte errorId { get; set; }
    public string errorDescription { get; set; }
    public string errorObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

I then call the API using a `TicketNumber` that *exists*.
I'm using [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/) for calling the api:

```
public async void SendRequestAndReceiveResponse()
{
    var restClient = new RestClient("https://someapiaddress.net");
    var requestXMLBody = "<request><request_id>1</request_id><operation>retrieve</operation><method /><entity>ticket</entity><user>someuser</user><password>somepassword</password><body><ticket><TicketNumber>12345</TicketNumber></ticket></body></request>";
    var request = new RestRequest("somexmlwebservice!process.action", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("xmlRequest", requestXMLBody, "text/xml", ParameterType.QueryString);
    var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<TicketsResponse>(request);
    // Do other stuffs with this response...
}
```

Now this works very well. Because I know my response will have the ticket and that will correctly deserialize to `TicketsResponse` object.

But if I call the API using a `TicketNumber` that doesn't exist, I simply get `TicketsResponse` object that has an empty list of `Tickets` because this time I'm getting error response. The status code comes to be `OK` in this case too.

What I want to do here is that I want to capture the error message from the error response. (Response of either *Ticket* or *Error* applies to bunch of other processes as well, so it's important to grab this information in a single call.)

And if I knew this ticket doesn't exist, I could simply call the API this way and capture the `errors`. But that's not ideal nor even a good idea:

```
var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<ErrorResponse>(request);
```

So I thought of combining `TicketsResponse` and `ErrorResponse`, like this:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class CombinedResponse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tickets")]
    public TicketsResponse Data { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "response")]
    public ErrorResponse NonData { get; set; }
}
```

And get the response using that class:

```
var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync<CombinedResponse>(request);
```

The Status code comes `OK` (when it returns either data or error message) and I get my correct response in `response.Content`, but the deserialization doesn't work, so my `response.Data` will show 2 fields `Data` and `NonData` both as `null`. Ideally I should have gotten either my *Ticket* data or *Error* data in `response.Data`.

**So my question is:**

Is it possible to make this work using a single class for deserialization?

I have spent too much time on this so any help is appreciated.
Also please look at my model classes and suggest if there's better way of doing things.

Comment: Can you show _how_ you're making the http call and parsing the response? Does the HTTP Status Code change in line with the XML schema returned?

Comment: You can create a single C# class by combining all of those fields and properties into 1 class. I'm curious why you want  only 1 class? Also, if you are using Visual Studio, you can copy the XML data, and use the menu Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as classes.

Comment: Try using a controller.  It can handle the multiple types of responses and put results in the classes you posted above : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/overview/understanding-models-views-and-controllers-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: @gunr2171 Sorry for my late response. I just added all that I have done so far to the original question. Please take a look.

Comment: @thewallrus I tried combining them into a single class. And I also updated my question with the reason of why I would want that. And I don't like pasting XML as classes in Visual Studio as it generates classes with properties that aren't auto implemented (at least that's my experience, maybe I'm doing it wrong).

Comment: @jdweng Sorry I don't quite follow. Any example would be helpful. Also I just updated my question with my effort so far, so you can take a look at it again.

Comment: The controller handles the Request/Response and does following 1) Manages the User Groups (permissions) 2) Allow for multiple different types of request responses (does deserializations) 3)  Allows for different formats like text, java and xml

Comment: I think, you have to implement your [custom deserializer](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#custom).  Within `Deserialize<T>()` you check if the given type is a `CombinedResponse` and if yes, you create an empty instance of it and call the default deserializer for the given response content for both types of your combined response and fill that result into both properties.  Maybe you can put in some checks to fill *the right* property only and keep the other at null. So a consumer could easily check for nullity of the properties of the combined response.

Comment: @Oliver Thank you for the response. I'm not sure how to implement your answer. An example would be helpful. I just posted my answer, if you have suggestions or ideas to improve it, please let me know. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue.
I'm posting here so others may find it helpful.

If there's a better way of doing this, please advise.

I created a method to call the API and deserialize the response to multiple types:

```
public async Task<(T1, T2)> SendRequestAndReceiveResponse<T1, T2>(RestRequest request)
{
    // This can be done in the constructor so we don't instantiate new client for every request.
    var restClient = new RestClient("https://someapiaddress.net");
        
    // Get response:
    var response = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(request);
    // Log request and response here if you want.

    if (response.ErrorException != null)
    {
        var message = $"An error occured during this request. Check request response entries for more details.";
        var newException = new Exception(message, response.ErrorException);
        throw newException;
    }
    else
    {
        var xmlDeserilizer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer();
        var data = xmlDeserilizer.Deserialize<T1>(response);
        var nonData = xmlDeserilizer.Deserialize<T2>(response);
        return (data, nonData);
    }
}
```

And used it, by sending the types I need:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Ticket>> FetchTickets()
{
    var xmlRequestBody = "<request><request_id>1</request_id><operation>retrieve</operation><method /><entity>ticket</entity><user>someuser</user><password>somepassword</password><body><ticket><TicketNumber>12345</TicketNumber></ticket></body></request>";
    var request = new RestRequest("somexmlwebservice!process.action", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("xmlRequest", xmlRequestBody, "text/xml", ParameterType.QueryString);
        
    var apiCallResult = await SendRequestAndReceiveResponse<TicketsResponse, ErrorResponse>(request);

    if (apiCallResult.Item1 != null && apiCallResult.Item1.HasTickets())
    {
        // Do something with the tickets...
    }
    else if (apiCallResult.Item2 != null && apiCallResult.Item2.HasErrors())
    {
        // Do something with the errors...
    }
    // And so on...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My complete solution. If you just need the answer, please take a look at the accepted answer.

This is more like a documentation of the whole process for anyone who deals with RestSharp and XML.

### Request:

To form a request body that looks like this, we need few classes like below:
[image]

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "request")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(RequestBodyWithTicketNumberOnly))] // To make sure 'body' can be serialized to RequestBodyWithTicketNumberOnly
public class TicketRequestBase
{
    public byte request_id { get; set; }
    public string operation { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public string entity { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    // body can have different shapes, so not giving it any specific class name.
    public object body { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "body")]
public class RequestBodyWithTicketNumberOnly
{
    public TicketWithTicketNumberOnly ticket { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ticket")]
public class TicketWithTicketNumberOnly
{
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
}
```

A method to convert C# objects into XML strings, like so:

```
public static string ToXml<T>(T obj)
{
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = false,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None,
        NewLineOnAttributes = false
    };

    var objType = obj.GetType();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objType);
    var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });

    using (var stream = new StringWriter())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj, emptyNamespaces);
        return stream.ToString();
    }
}
```

A method to return request body as XML string:

```
public static string GetTicketFetchRequestBody(string ticketNumber)
{
    if (ticketNumber== null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ticketNumber));

    var singleTicketRequest = new TicketRequestBase()
    {
        request_id = 1,
        operation = "retrieve",
        method = string.Empty,
        entity = "ticket",
        user = "sauser",
        password = "sapassword",
        body = new RequestBodyWithTicketNumberOnly() { ticket = new TicketWithTicketNumberOnly { TicketNumber = ticketNumber} }
    };

    return ToXml(singleTicketRequest);
}
```

### Response:

All the classes for the response are already documented in this question. Please take a look at them.

The top level method that gets the *Ticket*:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Ticket>> FetchTickets()
{
    var xmlRequestBody = GetTicketFetchRequestBody("12345");
    var request = new RestRequest("somexmlwebservice!process.action", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("xmlRequest", xmlRequestBody, "text/xml", ParameterType.QueryString);
        
    var apiCallResult = await SendRequestAndReceiveResponse<TicketsResponse, ErrorResponse>(request);

    if (apiCallResult.Item1 != null && apiCallResult.Item1.HasTickets())
    {
        // Do something with the tickets...
    }
    else if (apiCallResult.Item2 != null && apiCallResult.Item2.HasErrors())
    {
        // Do something with the errors...
    }
    // And so on...
}
```

The method that actually calls the API uses Proxy, logs requests and responses, and executes request using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) retry policy:

```
public async Task<(T1, T2)> SendRequestAndReceiveResponse<T1, T2>(RestRequest request, bool useProxy = true)
{
    // This can be done in the constructor so we don't instantiate new client for every request.
    var restClient = new RestClient("https://someapiaddress.net");
    
    if (useProxy) // This variable can even be initialized in the constructor of this RestClient
    {
        var proxy = GetWebProxy();
        restClient.Proxy = proxy;
    }

    // Request Logging Part:
    var requestAsJSONString = GetRequestForLogging(request, restClient);
    // Log it using your logging provider.

    // Response Part:
    var response = await ExecuteAsyncWithPolicy(request, restClient);

    // Response Logging Part:
    var responseAsString = response.Content;
    // Log it using your logging provider.

    if (response.ErrorException != null)
    {
        var message = $"An error occured during this request. Check request response entries for more details.";
        var newException = new Exception(message, response.ErrorException);
        throw newException;
    }
    else
    {
        var xmlDeserilizer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer();
        var data = xmlDeserilizer.Deserialize<T1>(response);
        var nonData = xmlDeserilizer.Deserialize<T2>(response);
        return (data, nonData);
    }
}
```

Create Web proxy like so:

```
private static WebProxy GetWebProxy()
{
    var proxyUrl = "http://proxy.companyname.com:9090/";
    return new WebProxy()
    {
        Address = new Uri(proxyUrl),
        BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
        //UseDefaultCredentials = true, // This uses: Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        //*** These creds are given to the proxy server, not the web server ***
        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        //Credentials = new NetworkCredential("proxyUserName", "proxyPassword")
    };
}
```

Create the request string with all the parameters like so:

```
private string GetRequestForLogging(IRestRequest request, IRestClient client)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    var requestToLog = new
    {
        // This will generate the actual Uri used in the request
        RequestUri = client.BuildUri(request),
        // Parameters are custom anonymous objects in order to have the parameter type as a nice string
        // otherwise it will just show the enum value
        parameters = request.Parameters.Select(parameter => new
        {
            name = parameter.Name,
            value = parameter.Value,
            type = parameter.Type.ToString()
        }),
        // ToString() here to have the method as a nice string otherwise it will just show the enum value
        method = request.Method.ToString()
    };

    return serializer.Serialize(requestToLog);
}
```

[*Polly*](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) retry policy:

```
private AsyncPolicy<IRestResponse> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    var policy = Polly.Policy.HandleResult<IRestResponse>((response) =>
    {
        return response.ResponseStatus != ResponseStatus.Completed;
    })
    //.Or<SomeKindOfCustomException>()
    .RetryAsync();

    return policy;
}
```

Call the API using the retry policy:

```
private async Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteAsyncWithPolicy(IRestRequest request, IRestClient restClient)
{
    var policy = GetRetryPolicy();
    var policyResult = await policy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(async () => await restClient.ExecuteAsync(request));

    return (policyResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful) ? policyResult.Result : new RestResponse
    {
        Request = request,
        ErrorException = policyResult.FinalException
    };
}
```

Hope this was helpful.